# AGAL - Optcode NRM - normalize the vector to size 1 - why it is used?

Tags: flash, starling-framework, stage3d, agal

Good evening everyone!

I have a sample of code which I am trying to understand:

```
// fragment
tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,repeat,linear,miplinear>
nrm ft1.xyz, v1
nrm ft2.xyz, v2
nrm ft3.xyz, v3
dp3 ft5.x, ft1.xyz, ft2.xyz
max ft5.x, ft5.x, fc0.x
add ft5, fc1, ft5.x
mul ft0, ft0, ft5
mov oc, ft0
```

Although I cannot imagine most operation (I try to do all calculation on paper in order to understanf the meaning of the program - I guess it is possible) but the NRM optcode confuses me most of all. I cannot understand why we do it. As I found every vector has length from 0,0,0 to its coordinates. Normalised vector has length 1. How can this help for calculations? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Normalised vectors are useful for calculating dot products between two vectors. For example, if the 'normal' of a model's face (the vector pointing out at 90 degrees to the face) is not normalised, you will get very odd results if you dot product it with another vector.

Comment: Thank you so much! It does help me! I do not understand clearly what is dot products dot products = Float values? sorry please if it is stupid question of mine...

Comment: The dot product between two vectors measures how 'parallel' they are. It is a single number and the result will be in the range of -1 to 1. If both vectors are pointing in the same direction their dot product is 1. If they're pointing at 90 degrees to one another (perpendicular) the dot product is 0, and if they're pointing in opposite directions the result is -1. So, effectively, the dot product of 2 vectors is the cosine of the angle between them. It can be very useful for plotting reflections and (in AS) calculating physics.

Comment: Thank you! As I see the Dot operation may be as following : nrm ft1.xyz, v1
nrm ft2.xyz, v2
nrm ft3.xyz, v3
dp3 ft5.x, ft1.xyz, ft2.xyz  first two lines normalize vectors and the last one calculates dot product?

Comment: Yes, the last line calculates the dot product of register ft1 (which contains the normalised values passed through register v1) and in ft2 (normalised, from v2). The resulting value (a number from -1 to 1) is put in the first component (.x) of register ft5.

Comment: Oh, and if you think your question has been answered, feel free to accept an answer...